# No appenders could be found for logger (selenium webdriver+testng)

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j, testng

I need implement log4j in my maven project. I have testng selenium test.
This is my log4j.properties file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\loging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

In test class I set logger: `private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Item.class);` and in method `log.warn("Low fuel level.");`
But when I run my test, get

```
 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger   (org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager).
 log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
 log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

log4j.properties is in the same package as my test

Answer (score 0):

Even i have faced this issue. But here is the solution for the issue:

**Step 1:** Zip the file "log4j.properties" and rename it to log4jprops.jar

**Step 2:** Go to Eclipse>Run>Run Configurations> and click on classpath tab

**Step 3:** Create a new classpath variable and give the filepath for the "log4jprops.jar";created earlier

Hope this should fix the problem!!

Thanks,